# How to write £1 million where style guide clashes

Tags: numbers, money

I am writing the figure of £1,000,000 in a presentation but finding that my style guide clashes with what looks right.

- 'Million' must be spelled out.
- '£' must be used instead of 'pounds'.
- Numbers one to ten must be written out and not expressed in numerals.

As such, it appears that I should present *£1,000,000* as *£one million* but this looks so odd. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

I have worked for a number of UK academic publishers and they all have'£1 million' (with lowercase m) as their house style. Occasionally, I have seen 1 million GBP. Incidentally, most publishers prefer numbers up to ten (or twenty) to be spelled out. This rule is usually 'bent' if it would create sentences such as: ' ... between eight and 12 people'. The guiding principle is to avoid cluttering the page with numerals whilst making sure that readers don't have to wade through too many spelled-out numbers. It's all to do with ease of reading as well as consistency.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case £1 million would be the correct form.

Comment: To expand, 1 in this case is _not_ the number one, but the amount of millions.

Comment: I don't follow your comment. How can '1' not be the number one? It is used in adjective form, granted, but that doesn't make it any less of a number than its noun counterpart, surely?

Comment: In the context it's actually a million. To make this clearer, the style guide won't suggest you write 121 as 'one two one'. The only difference here is the following digits _are_ converted to 'million' by the style guide, but the first digit remains.

Comment: Okay, I see what you're saying from your second sentence onwards, but if we were to consider '£1 million' ignoring the currency symbol then I would, without hesitation, write this as 'one million' as per the style guide. As such, my question isn't really about the number one million itself but the way this number interacts with a currency symbol in its written forms as per the style guide.

Comment: You may write one million without hessitation, but it may not actually be the ideal . For example, the guardian (UK) style guide says '1 million people,' despite spelling out any number below ten.

Comment: When you have a style guide, an 'ideal' is something that conforms to the style guide unless the style guide leads to something obscure such as writing one million pounds as '£one million'. The Guardian's style guide means nothing to me because the crux of my question pertains to staying within the lines of an already-determined style guide.

Comment: I was just bringing up the guardian as it also has the rules of your style guide in that normally 'one' is spelled out, and 'million' is as well. When I wrote 'may not be the ideal' is due to the fact that I believe it to be wrong, but am not sure if anyone will pull you up on it, as the s.g. is not explicit enough in this case. You may find it useful to see what others using the same style guide as you have done in the oast.